# Solution to $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\frac{kx}{m}=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

This is the system of differential equations which describes simple harmonic motion:
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\frac{kx}{m}=0$$
$$x(0)=A$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}=0$$

By guessing that $x$ is of the form $A\cos\left(\omega t+\phi\right)$, I can arrive at the solution following solution: $$x=A\cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\text{ }t\right)$$

My question is, how can you derive this solution **without** assuming that $x$ is a sinusoidal function? I have not yet taken a formal calculus course, so a simple solution would be appreciated.

Comment: what is about a series ansatz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the problem statement, the ODE $m\ddot{x}+k x=0$ describes simple harmonic motion. More precisely, it's the equation of motion of such a system (i.e. Newton's second law).

What's more crucial for the present purpose, however, is not Newton's laws but rather *energy conservation*. To reveal this, suppose we multiply both sides of the equation of motion by $\dot{x}$ to get 
$$0=m\dot{x}\ddot{x}+k x\dot{x}=mv\frac{dv}{dt}+kx\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac12 m v^2+\frac12 k x^2\right)$$
from which we conclude that the energy $E=\frac12 mv^2+\frac12 k x^2$ is conserved. For the initial conditions in the problem, we specifically have

$$\frac12 m\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\frac12 k x^2=\frac12 k A^2.$$

Why is energy conservation useful? Because this ODE is separable:

$$t=\int_{A}^{x(t)}\frac{dx}{dx/dt}=-\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}} \int_{A}^{x(t)}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{A^2-x^2}}.$$

(The minus sign is because, if the object starts from rest with $x(0)=A>0$, it will begin moving with a *negative* velocity. Other such sign issues can be clarified if one is careful.) Either by trig substitution or by using a table of integrals, one obtains
$$t=\sqrt{\frac m k}\cos^{-1} \frac{x(t)}{A}\implies x(t)=A\cos(t\sqrt{k/m}).$$ So it is indeed a sinusoidal motion.

Answer (score 1):

You might be surprised that one of the most general ways to solve differential equations is to *guess the solution*. Differential equations are different from algebraic equations in that respect. I will show you a method here that involves another form of guessing, but it is *slightly* more general.

You may not have taken a formal calculus course, but you may know Euler's identity
$$
\tag{$*$}e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x,
$$
which relates the exponential $e$ to $\sin$ and $\cos$. Then what you can do is a *little* more general than guessing the solution is of the form $A\cos (\omega t + \phi)$. You can guess the solution is of the form $x(t) = e^{\lambda t},$ and not give a care about what $\lambda$ is, but find out. Put $k/m := \omega^2$.
$$
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\omega^2 x=0 \\
\lambda^2e^{\lambda t} + \omega^2e^{\lambda t} = 0
$$
and since $e^{\lambda t} \ne 0$, we can divide by $e^{\lambda t}$ on each side of our equation:
$$
\lambda^2 + \omega^2 = 0 \\
\lambda^2 = -\omega^2 \\
\lambda = \pm i\omega.
$$
Note that we don't give a care what $\lambda$ is beforehand. We just assume the solution can be some $\lambda$, and intrepidly proceed until we can go no further.
We find out that one solution of our equation is $x_1(t) = e^{i\omega t}$ as you can check by differentiating:
$$
\frac{d^2x_1}{dt^2}+\omega^2 x_1=0 \\
(i\omega)^2e^{i\omega t} + \omega^2e^{i\omega t} = 0 \\
-\omega^2e^{i\omega t} + \omega^2e^{i\omega t} = 0 \\
(-\omega^2 + \omega^2)e^{i\omega t} = 0 \\
0e^{i\omega t} = 0\, \checkmark.
$$
And other solution is $x_2(t) = e^{-i\omega t}$ as you can check by differentiating:
$$
\frac{d^2x_2}{dt^2}+\omega^2 x_2=0 \\
(-i\omega)^2e^{-i\omega t} + \omega^2e^{-i\omega t} = 0 \\
-\omega^2e^{-i\omega t} + \omega^2e^{-i\omega t} = 0 \\
(-\omega^2 + \omega^2)e^{-i\omega t} = 0 \\
0e^{-i\omega t} = 0\, \checkmark.
$$
The most general solution to the problem is then some sum of these two solutions
$$
x(t) = Ce^{i\omega t} + De^{-i\omega t}.
$$
Using our initial conditions that $x(0) = A$ and $x'(0) = 0$, we have
$$
x(0) = Ce^0 + De^0 = A \\
\therefore C + D = A \\
x'(0) = i\omega Ce^0 - i\omega De^0 = 0 \\
\therefore C = D = A/2 \\
x(t) = \tfrac{A}{2}(\cos \omega t + i\sin\omega t) + \tfrac{A}{2}(\cos\omega t - i\sin\omega t) \\
x(t) = A\cos\omega t.
$$
Hence, our particular solution is $x(t) = A\cos\omega t$. If our solution turned out to involve the imaginary number $i$, we know that whenever we measure the position of the mass on the spring, we should get a real number. However, $e^{i\omega t}$ is a *complex* number and it has an *imaginary part*. Our solution should be *real*, so we take what's known as the *real part* of our solution, which is the $\cos$ part of $(*)$.

Unfortunately, methods for solving differential equations are generally different than solving algebraic equations, until you learn plenty more calculus. This method is a little more general than guessing $\cos$ or $\sin$ because we don't assume it has to be one or the other. We assume it is some combination of them both, and that we can find out by solving for $\lambda$.

Answer (score -1):

Solution(Partial): $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\frac{kx}{m}$$ $$\implies 2\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-2\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{kx}{m}$$ 
On integrating both sides: 
$$\implies (\frac{dx}{dt})^2=-\frac{2kx^2}{m}+C$$ Using the initial conditions we get: $$C=\frac{2kA^2}{m}$$
$$\implies \frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt\frac{2k}{m}\sqrt{(A^2-x^2)}$$ I think you can take it from here.